# Questions around modelling arrival process of randomly sized groups

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution, point-process, compound-distributions

I have the following situation:

I'm trying to model groups arriving to some location by some process. I assume the distribution on some interval $T$ is a Gamma-Poisson mixture where $\Lambda \sim Gamma(k, \theta)$ with $k$, $\theta$ (shape, scale) known. I then get the marginal distribution of the number of groups arriving over $T$ as $N \sim NB(k, \frac{1}{1+\theta})$ [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture) where $NB$ is the Negative Binomial distribution with support on $\{0,1,...\}$.

Now  I have two questions:

1. Each group is of some unknown size (nr of people in the group) with an empirical average size of $a$. I assume these groups $G_1, ..., G_N$ are independent random variables distributed as $\text{Geometric}(1/a)$. I'm interested in the distribution of the total amount of people arriving which would then be the sum of these groups which [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Distribution_of_a_sum_of_geometrically_distributed_random_variables) has a Negative Binomial distribution too. So the distribution of the total amound of people arriving would then be $A \sim \text{NB}(N,1/a)$. So it's a Negative Binomial where $N$ is itself a Negative Binomial as above. I would like to find a closed form expression for the marginal distribution of $A$ if possible. I started trying to marginalize out $N$ but it ends up as a series of quite complex terms *so I wonder if there are other better ways to find closed form expressions to things like this?*
2. In case there is no closed form expression I thought I could try to approximate the marginal distribution of $A$ by simply scaling $N$ by $a$. However I'm unsure of whether this even makes sense and which distribution I should scale in that case. If I should just scale $N$, as $Y = aN$ (and I was unable to find results of whether this would still be a Negative Binomial and if so how the parameters $k$ and $1/(1+\theta)$ would be affected) or since the distribution of $N$ is the result of a Poisson-Gamma mixture would it make sense to scale the intensity $\Lambda$ so that $a\Lambda \sim Gamma(k, a\theta) \Rightarrow N \sim NB(k, \frac{1}{1+a\theta})$. *Any thoughts on this given the situation I'm trying to model?*

Comment: So in short, you are looking for an expression of compounding a negative binomial with another negative binomial?

Comment: Yes, a close form expression. I’m going to implement this model and would like to avoid having to compute each term in the series due to performance constraints. If no close form exists I would like to understand how scaling a Negative Binomial by a constant would affect it and whether it’s sensible compared to scaling the underlying Gamma distributed intensity r.v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short it seems like you are looking for an expression of compounding a negative binomial with another negative binomial.

We can express a negative binomial distributed variable as a coin flip process where we flip coin 1 with $p_1$ probability of success untill $k$ successes, and for each flip with coin 1 we flip a second coin woth parameter $p_2$ untill a success with that coin before we proceed to the next flip with the first coin.

For example if $k=3$, then a sample could look like

```
coin 1  coin 2 
F       FFS
F       S
F       FS
S       FFFS
F       FS
S       S
F       S
F       FFFFS
S       FS
```

So we have 9 flips with coin 1 untill 2 successes

```
FFFSFSFFS
```

And we have 21 flips with coin 2 untill 9 successes

```
FFSSFSFFFSFSSSFFFFSFS
```

We can also regard this process differently and flip coin 2, and each succes of coin 2 we also flip coin 1 to see if that has a success too. And perform such process untill we got 3 successes with coin 1

```
Coin 2 FFSSFSFFFSFSSSFFFFSFS
Coin 1   FF F   S FSF    F S
```

This is like a negative binomial process where we flip both coin 1 and coin 2 together and regard a success when both coins are a success.

So if $$N \sim NB(k,p_1) \\ X \sim NB(N,p_2)$$ then this compound process is the same as $$X \sim NB(k,p_1 \cdot p_2)$$